# How do you redirect to previous page in Flask after user has logged in through Google Authentication

Tags: python, flask, google-authentication

I have a Flask webapp that does NOT use flask-login. I was following this tutorial to use [Google Authentication with Flask](https://www.mattbutton.com/2019/01/05/google-authentication-with-python-and-flask/).

What is the best way to redirect the user to the previous page (that was accessed before the redirect to the login page)? Right now my app will redirect to the index page ('/') after login.

I have tried to add in a url key to the flask session and redirect to the session['url'] in the login function, but I ended up with too many redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the redirect URI when redirecting the user to the login page. In the tutorial you are following, the redirect URI is saved in an environment variable called `FN_AUTH_REDIRECT_URI`. If you change that (and add the new URI to the list of allowed redirect URIs in the Google Cloud OAuth client id) you will be redirected to the correct page.